WCF with Named Pipes and WPF - Timeout with time-consuming operations
I'm struggling with the project that are copying files from the network(CIFS share).
IPC which I'm using is Named Net Pipes with Duplex Channel and for GUI I'm using WPF.
The application is communicating only between the service and the UI on the same machine.
Problem is confusing, because I've prepare some time consuming methods like copying entire directories from the CIFS share to the Client, and during the copy I've encountered many times a problem like this:

System.TimeoutException: 'This request operation sent to net.pipe://localhost/service did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.'

I was researching for the solution and I found that the timeout can be increased, but it did not solves my problem.
For small directories it could be fine to increase the timeout to e.g. 3-4 minutes, but for large ones that can weight more than 1GB it could be a big problem.
Independent actions will also take place in the background, such as checking every few minutes if a given CIFS share is responding or logging the application status regardless of what is currently happening (I mean user actions). I use asynchrony, among others, using Tasks, but I'm not sure if it works well with Named Pipes.
I've even prepared a Callback interface that returns a progress of copying, thinking that it could help "hold" the timeout, but it did not.
I'm at a dead end now, because I started testing this solution with a Service separate from the GUI, which contains all the application logic. Does anyone have an idea what I could change, or possibly what technology to use to maintain the idea of ​​separation and similar communication? The separation of these two processes is caused by the difference in user permissions.

@Edit
There are two interfaces that I use:
    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICopierCallbackService))]
    public interface ICopierService
    {        
        [OperationContract]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(PackagePart))]
        Task<List<Package>> CheckPackages();
    }
    
    [ServiceContract]   
    public interface ICopierCallbackService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void GetTime(string time);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void ReportCopyProgress(string source, string destination, int progress);
    }

I created additional class related to this copying (CopyProgressEventArgs) which implements EventArgs, that allows to pass more than 2 params unlike the typical use of "Invoke".
This is my "ServiceClient":
public class ServiceClient : ICopierCallbackService
    {
        private ICopierService _serviceProxy;
        private DuplexChannelFactory<ICopierService> _duplexChannelFactory;
        private const string NamedPipeAddress = "net.pipe://localhost/service";
        public event EventHandler<CopyProgressEventArgs> CopyProgressChanged;

        public ServiceClient()
        {
            _duplexChannelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<ICopierService>(this, new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress(NamedPipeAddress));
            _serviceProxy = _duplexChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        }

        public async Task<List<Package>> CheckPackages()
        {
            List<Package> packages = await _serviceProxy.CheckPackages();

            return packages;
        }

        public void ReportCopyProgress(string source, string destination, int progress)
        {
            CopyProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, new CopyProgressEventArgs(source, destination, progress));
        }
    }

And finally in the ViewModel I've prepared a property for monitoring whether the progress has changed, and currently printing it using System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline gives me a valid output to the console.

@Edit 2
CheckPackages retrieves some data through API, then Deserializes it etc.:
public async Task<List<Package>> CheckPackages(ICopierCallbackService callback)
        {
            Root root = await ApiHandler.FetchClientPackages(_Settings.Hostname);

            List<Package> packages = root.Data.Packages;

            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(_Settings.LocalPackagesRealPath);

            FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");

            packages = await AdjustPackage(files, packages);

            // here I'm getting some constant file paths and copying them using belows method
            await CopyIcons(callback);

            return packages;
        }

Example method that triggers the ReportCopyProgress - I have multiple versions of them, depends of what needs to be copied:
private static async Task<bool> CopyDirectoryInternalAsync(string sourceDirectoryPath, string destinationDirectoryPath, ICopierCallbackService callback)
        {
            try
            {
                EnsureDirectoryExists(destinationDirectoryPath);

                var sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectoryPath);
                for (int i = 0; i < sourceFiles.Length; i++)
                {
                    var sourceFilePath = sourceFiles[i];
                    var destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryPath, Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath));

                    bool success = await CopyFileInternalAsync(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath, callback);

                    if (callback != null)
                    {
                        int progress = (int)((i + 1) / (double)sourceFiles.Length * 100);
                        callback.ReportCopyProgress(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath, progress);
                    }

                    if (!success)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                var subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDirectoryPath);
                foreach (var subDirectory in subDirectories)
                {
                    var destinationSubDirectory = Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryPath, Path.GetFileName(subDirectory));
                    bool success = await CopyDirectoryInternalAsync(subDirectory, destinationSubDirectory, callback);

                    if (!success)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error copying directory: {ex.Message}");
                return false;
            }
        }


You probably do not want to have one long running RPC call. Consider having a "Start" call that returns some sort of handle/Operation-Identifier, a "Status" call to poll progress of that operation and if needed a "End" call if you have information you need to gather after the operation has finished.

The same problem exists in all technologies - if you start a long-running job and block until it finishes, you'll get a timeout at some point. If there was no timeout, a bad job could run indefinitely, blocking the server. The solution is to run the jobs in the background and either send progress updates to the caller or have the caller poll the service to get the progress. Using a Duplex channel should allow the service to send notifications to the client

You may call the service asynchronously, as explained here.

@Clemens that link only refers to the pre-4.5 way of asynchronous calls, that was replaced by async/await. It won't prevent server-side timeouts.

@kalview what does the implementation and callback contract look like? The error says there was no reply, not even callbacks, in 1 minute. If you're trying to move 1GB though, it's probably better to just start the job and poll its status

@PanagiotisKanavos, I've edited the topic adding some code.

That's not the service code. Post the code that calls ReportCopyProgress. What does CheckPackages do? This looks more and more an attempt to create something similar to Coravel, Hangfire or Quartz.NET with a WCF frontend. You can use one of those scheduler libraries in your service and only use WCF operations to trigger jobs

@PanagiotisKanavos added the code. There are simple methods for copying and inside that I'm using this callback.

So, you suggest to keep Named Pipes but only for triggering the time consuming methods and adding them to some kind of queue of scheduled jobs? I'm wondering how now I can monitor what's happening inside the method to give some feedback to the GUI.

To me this looks like you are deserting communication. If you receive file by file or folder by folder your client is busy with copying those large filesystem items. Meanwhile the server keeps pumping. Because your client is busy with processing the received data the service times out as it "thinks" that the client is gone. One solution could be to implement a producer-consumer pattern. For example, the .NET Channel provides good performance and has a modern async API.

You basically need the client to drain the pipe as data arrives and enqueue it for later processing. I think you should try this. Channels are really easy to use. You basically only need await reader.WaitToReadAsync and await writer.WriteAsync:  System.Threading.Channels library.

Maybe you also want to consider replacing the old WCF with the newer gRPC Inter-process communication with gRPC. You can easily configure the gRPC server to use named pipes instead of sockets if you want (see the provided link). gRPC is significantly faster than WCF which should have relevance in your scenario.

To further improve the performance (especially the time factor) you should not use Directory.GetFiles and Directory.GetDirectories. Instead, consider using Directory.EnumerateFiles and Directory.EnumerateDirectories. This saves you a complete iteration (you are currently iterating the whole filesystem twice) and gives you more control over the read items and the chance to configure how the Directory class is handling access violations (by using a corresponding overload). This allows you to avoid the related exception handling, which further speeds up your algorithm.

Thanks @BionicCode, I was thinking about gRPC and complete move to .NET 8 & something that replace WPF also like e.g. MAUI. Can gRPC be hosted locally like WCF in Windows Service?

Yes of course. You can use it locally or across networks. By default, it uses TCP sockets with HTTP/2 for the fast performance, but you can tell it to use pipes too (for IPC).  This Startup.cs and Program.cs is an example of a service configuring the gRPC server. It's pretty straight forward as Microsoft hass built-in the support. This gives you an idea. You only have to define the proto files and the actual gRPC service. This example uses the classic Windows Service.

The modern .NET approach would be to use BackgroundService to create a Windows service. Create Windows Service using BackgroundService

gRPC can be used across multiple platforms if that matters.

Thanks again @BionicCode, do you recommend something for the UI? The only platform it will run is Windows.

I can't answer this definitely because it really depends on your requirements. Skills probably also play a relevant role. You will be more productive if you use the platform, you already know, for sure. If I read your implications correctly then you are not interested in cross-platform application development. If you are firm with WPF then WPF is absolutely solid.

If you have just started with WPF then you can pick anything you want, learning curves will look similar. Desktop or browser-based? Up to your personal choice. I'm afraid you won't find this answer helpful. Maybe you just want to learn something new and productivity is not a concern. You know best I guess ;)

I'm curious if using a producer-consumer queue has solved your original problem.

@BionicCode I'll try to test it tomorrow and eventually I can let you know, because it requires a little bit of rebuilt.

Hello @BionicCode, I was testing finally a SignalR communication with Background Worker & WPF in .NET 8. So I've prepared couple of endpoints and it seems that monitoring those endpoints is quite smooth option - At the moment 3 concurrent action at one time and the communication is working without any timeouts.
